# How to place an image in a chapter title (perfectly centered)

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, chapters

**Before to begin, I know about:**

```
\chapter{My Chapter Title\hfill\includegraphics{image}}
```

But it's not what I'm searching.

I want the following result:

[image: Perfectly center]

Next are all the methods I tried (and their respective results):

```
\chapter{Devise}\tabto{13cm}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{DEVISE_logo.png}
```

[image: Too low]

```
\chapter[Devise]{Devise\hfill\parbox[c]{.5\textwidth}{\hfill\includegraphics[height=2cm]{DEVISE_logo.png}}}
```

[image: Too low]

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\linewidth}
    \chapter{Devise}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\linewidth}
    \hfill\includegraphics[height=2cm]{DEVISE_logo.png}
\end{minipage}
```

[image: Too high and offset]

```
\parbox[c]{.5\linewidth}{\chapter{Devise}}\parbox[c]{.5\linewidth}{\hfill\includegraphics[height=2cm]{DEVISE_logo.png}}
```

[image: To low and offset]

---

*PS: I post all the pictures with the same width so you can notice on the two last the chapter title is offset.*

---

Just to add to the solution found by John Kormylo:

Since he found the height of the chapter block (number + space + title) is 2.3cm, to place an image on the center line of this block, just do:

```
\savebox{\tempbox}{\raisebox{-((X-2.3)/2)cm}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=Xcm]{example-image}}}
```

*(Replace X by the height you want for your image)*

Comment: Try the `titlesec` package.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I watch. But if there is a way to do it and also keep the standard LaTeX chapter title, I would prefer.

Comment: Is this just for one chapter or shall this be applied to all chapters?

Comment: A lot depends on the font size used and the size of the gap.  Shall we assume standard book definitions, or just play with numbers until it fits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 22pt was found by trial and error.  It should represent the height of the font used for the title plus 1/2 the gap.  For some reason \chapter didn't like \raisebox, hence the \savebox.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
\savebox{\tempbox}{\raisebox{22pt}[\height]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}}
\chapter[My Chapter Title]{My Chapter Title\hfill\usebox{\tempbox}}% corrected

This space left blank.
\end{document}
```

[image: chapter title]

Here is an alternate form to overlap the text.  Again, the 2.3cm was found by trial and error.

```
\savebox{\tempbox}{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image}}}
```

[image: overlap]

Comment: You should also use the optional argument, or the TOC and headers will have small problems.

Comment: Uh, so what should I use for the optional argument?  The manual isn't very clear.

Comment: @JohnKormylo what egreg means is to use the optional argument for `\chapter`, as in `\chapter[My chapter title]{My Chapter Title\hfill\usebox{\tempbox}}.

Comment: Huh.  I got the impression that the optional argument was supposed to be a counter.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I use your answer: by configuring the first parameter of raisebox at -Xcm it do what I want. Now, is there somewhere I can see the height of the block "Chapter N Title" so I can make a calculus to center the image in function of the height ?

Comment: Forget about my above comment: thanks to your tests, I know it makes 2.3cm of height --> Once again, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Here's a mildly more complicated solution: the picture, with possible options, is given as a trailing optional argument to `\chapter`.

It would be possible to use the standard `\chapter` syntax and define a `\chapterfigure` command that needs to be placed just before `\chapter`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{xparse,graphicx,xpatch}
\let\latexchapter\chapter

\ExplSyntaxOn

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{somo}
 {
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_matthieu_chapter_figure_bool
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\latexchapter*{#3}}
   {
    \IfNoValueTF{#4}
     {
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\latexchapter{#3}}
       {\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}
     }
     {
      \bool_gset_true:N \g_matthieu_chapter_figure_bool
      \placefigure{#4}
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\latexchapter{#3}}
       {\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}
     }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\placefigure}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { matthieu/placefigure } { #1 }
  \matthieu_placefigure:V \l_matthieu_placefigure_options_tl
 }

\keys_define:nn { matthieu/placefigure }
 {
  options .tl_set:N  = \l_matthieu_placefigure_options_tl,
  file    .tl_set:N  = \l_matthieu_placefigure_file_tl,
  file    .initial:n = {},
 }

\box_new:N \l_matthieu_figure_box
\dim_new:N \l_matthieu_halfheight_dim
\bool_new:N \g_matthieu_chapter_figure_bool

\cs_new_protected:Npn \matthieu_placefigure:n #1
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_matthieu_figure_box
   {
    \includegraphics[#1]{ \l_matthieu_placefigure_file_tl }
   }
  \hbox_set_to_wd:Nnn \l_matthieu_figure_box { \textwidth }
   {
    \hfil
    \box_move_down:nn { \box_ht:N \l_matthieu_figure_box / 2 }
     { \box_use:N \l_matthieu_figure_box }
   }
  \box_set_ht:Nn \l_matthieu_figure_box { 0pt }
  \box_set_dp:Nn \l_matthieu_figure_box { 0pt }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \matthieu_placefigure:n { V }

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
 { \vskip 20\p@ }
 {
  \vskip 10\p@ \nointerlineskip
  \bool_if:NT \g_matthieu_chapter_figure_bool { \box_use:N \l_matthieu_figure_box }
  \nointerlineskip
  \vskip 10\p@
 }
 {}{}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\let\cleardoublepage\relax % just to show a few chapters

\chapter{My chapter title}[
  file=example-image,
  options={width=3cm,height=2cm}
]


\chapter{My chapter title}[
  file=example-image,
  options={width=3cm,height=30pt}
]

\chapter{My chapter title}[
  file=example-image,
  options={width=3cm,height=10pt}
]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's hard to understand for a beginner like me but it's good to have some complicate example so I can use them latter to see how to configure deeply LaTeX commands. --> Thanks :)

Comment: @Matthieu.P The first part is just to add an optional argument to `\chapter`. The trick for centering is in the patch to `\@makechapterhead`, where the `\vskip20pt` is split into two and in the middle I set a zero height box that contains the image (flush right and centered with respect to its baseline).

Comment: Oh ok, now I understand ! (good idea) Thanks :)